# GWT RequestFactory calling setter on wrong object

Tags: java, gwt

Fist it's not the wrong object but it is not the correct reference as I have diagnosed the problem.

I have an editor where I am editing an object that contains another list editor of more beans.

I have a TagCollectionProxy and this contains a list of TagProxy objects. The problem occurs when I save the TagCollectionProxy with the attached List objects. My entity locator is looking up the object in the database and setting the value but then I don't have a reference to that object. This is new and I am not sure why this is happening now.

This debug message when I am calling save on the object. I have put a message in the Tag class on setValue and you can see that I am setting the correct value on the domain entity. The id matches. The problem comes in the next message for my save(TagCollection) in my dao class. I am iterating over the entities and printing the value but the value has not changed for that entity.

```
2014-08-29T15:34:15.912-0500|INFO: Setting value Tag2asdfasdfasdfasdf for id 294 Reference cpbx.rialto.dms.Tag@1135696
2014-08-29T15:34:15.944-0500|INFO: Tag name => asdfasdf Tag value => Tag2 id => 294 ref => cpbx.rialto.dms.Tag@1893889
2014-08-29T15:34:15.944-0500|INFO: Id of tag is 294
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I am loosing hair by the minute.

This is my Activity that saves the object. Notice that I am saving the TagCollectionProxy that contains the list of Tags.

```
public class TagCollectionEditActivity extends AbstractActivity<TagCollectionEditView> implements
        TagCollectionEditView.Presenter {



    private Receiver<Long> saveReceiver = new Receiver<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Long response) {
            logger.info("saved tagCollection with id of " + response);
            clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(new TagCollectionsPlace());
        }

        public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {

            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations) {
                logger.warning(violation.getMessage());
            }
            getDisplay().getEditorDriver().setConstraintViolations(violations);
        }

        public void onFailure(ServerFailure failure) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to save tag collection " + failure.getMessage());
            getDisplay().showError(failure);
        }
    };

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TagCollectionEditActivity.class.getName());

    private IClientFactory clientFactory;

    private TagCollectionDaoRequest editContext = null;

    public TagCollectionEditActivity(IClientFactory clientFactory) {
        super(new TagCollectionEditView(clientFactory.getResources(), clientFactory.getEventBus()));
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindToView() {
        getDisplay().setPresenter(this);
        final TagCollectionEditPlace place = (TagCollectionEditPlace) getPlace();
        Long tagCollectionId = place.getTagCollectionId();

        if (tagCollectionId == null) {
            createTagCollection();
        } else {
            findCollection(tagCollectionId);
        }
    }

    private void findCollection(Long tagCollectionId) {
        clientFactory.tagCollectionRequest().find(tagCollectionId).with(getEntityProperties())
                .fire(new Receiver<TagCollectionProxy>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(TagCollectionProxy tagCollection) {
                        editContext = clientFactory.tagCollectionRequest();
                        editContext.save(tagCollection).with(getDisplay().getEditorDriver().getPaths()).to(saveReceiver);
                        getDisplay().getEditorDriver().edit(tagCollection, editContext);
                        GWT.log("Context is " + editContext.hashCode());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void createTagCollection() {
        editContext = clientFactory.tagCollectionRequest();
        TagCollectionProxy tagCollection = editContext.create(TagCollectionProxy.class);
        editContext.save(tagCollection).with(getDisplay().getEditorDriver().getPaths()).to(saveReceiver);
        tagCollection.setTags(new ArrayList<TagProxy>());
        getDisplay().getEditorDriver().edit(tagCollection, editContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSave() {
        RequestContext context = getDisplay().getEditorDriver().flush();
        context.fire();
    }   

    public String[] getEntityProperties() {
        return new String[] { "tags", "deviceFamily" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(new TagCollectionsPlace());
    }
}
```

Here is my tag collection proxy where I define my DomainEntityLocator

```
@ProxyFor(value = TagCollection.class, locator = DomainEntityLocator.class)
public interface TagCollectionProxy extends DomainEntityProxy {

    public List<TagProxy> getTags();

    public void setTags(List<TagProxy> tags);

    public DeviceFamilyProxy getDeviceFamily();

    public void setDeviceFamily(DeviceFamilyProxy deviceFamily);

}
```

Here is my locator that uses the database to look up objects using a JPA entityManager.

```
public class DomainEntityLocator extends Locator<DomainEntity, Long> {

    private static EntityManager em = null;

    static {
        Context initCtx;
        try {
            initCtx = new InitialContext();
            // perform JNDI lookup to obtain container-managed entity manager
            em = (javax.persistence.EntityManager) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/DomainEntityManager");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get the domain entity manager");
        }
    }

    public DomainEntityLocator() {
    }

    @Override
    public DomainEntity create(Class<? extends DomainEntity> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DomainEntity find(Class<? extends DomainEntity> clazz, Long id) {
        return em.find(clazz, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DomainEntity> getDomainType() {
        return DomainEntity.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId(DomainEntity domainObject) {
        return domainObject.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Long> getIdType() {
        return Long.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getVersion(DomainEntity domainObject) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Update**

After some investigation, I realized that the JPA on the server side was to blame for my issue. I have come to the conclusion that the DomainEntityLocator is fetching the entity but is not wrapping that in a transaction. So the DomainEntityLocator#find() method will retrieve the entity and the ServiceLayer will modify the value on the entity. The problem I have is that the find method is not wrapped in a transaction and since the entity manager I am retrieving is not managed the entity manager is not flushing the changes. Hence I do not see the updates on the value.

**On Topic Question #2**

Is there a common pattern to adding transaction management to the Entity Locator so that it will persist the object after request factory calls the setters. I used to do this with a simple servlet filter but the project I am working on requires java ee for maintaining this kind of functionality. I can't make the DomainEntityLocator a Stateless bean because of the way the ServiceLayer will look it up. Would it be best to extend the RequestFactoryServlet and wrap the doPost in a tranasction? This seems like the most logical idea. Any suggestions?

Thanks again Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, RequestFactory will load each object by its ID, using your locator, so the `TagCollection` will be loaded (with its list of `Tag`) and each `Tag` will be loaded too using the `DomainEntityLocator` (assuming that's how they're declared in their `@ProxyFor`).
The setters will be called on the objects returned by the locator, not the ones from the `TagCollection`'s `getTags` list.

You have to make sure they are the same instances.

With JPA, that means using the "open session in view" (aka "session per request") pattern. A JPA session uses a cache, so sharing the same session across the whole HTTP request will make it sure that the same instances of `Tag` are used whenever loaded from the `TagCollection` or directly by their ID.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for the assistance. I came to the same conclusion as you after a little bit of debugging. My initial confusion stemmed from Chrome does not print the entire post message in the (debug tools) preview panel. I had to dig into the Header panel to see the entire outgoing message. I updated the question with a minor update. If you know of a good solution for wrapping the Locator in a transaction of if this is even a good idea please let me know.

Comment: Wrapping the whole request/response in a transaction is calling for trouble: RF semantics will change if you do that. What you need is the "open session in view" pattern (one `EntityManager` per request/response) and then scope your transactions to your service methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I did to solve the problem with EJB and RequestFactory.**

After figuring out that the RequestFactory method was not being wrapped in a transaction for the entity manager I had two choices that came to mind. One was I could add a UserTransaction to the Entity locator's find and create methods but I decided to wrap the entire request in a transaction and this works well for my case since my request factory methods should pretty much always be in a transaction.

I extended the requestfactory servlet and added a UserTransaction to the doPost.

```
@WebServlet("/rf/secure/dao")
public class DmsRequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -521670028586842819L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DmsRequestFactoryServlet.class.getName());

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;


    public static class SimpleExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {

        @Override
        public ServerFailure createServerFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to complete request", throwable);

            return new ServerFailure("Server Error: " + (throwable == null ? null : throwable.getMessage()), throwable
                    .getClass().getName(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            super.doPost(request, response);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed request ", e);
        }
    }

    public DmsRequestFactoryServlet() {
        super(new SimpleExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```